# VIEW SERVER STATE permission was denied on object 'server', database 'master'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, system-views

I am querying my database from an application and the following syntax is executable

```
SELECT t.name AS TableName
    ,i.name AS indexName
    ,sum(p.rows) AS RowCounts
    ,sum(a.total_pages) AS TotalPages
    ,sum(a.used_pages) AS UsedPages
    ,sum(a.data_pages) AS DataPages
    ,(sum(a.total_pages) * 8) / 1024 AS TotalSpaceMB
    ,(sum(a.used_pages) * 8) / 1024 AS UsedSpaceMB
    ,(sum(a.data_pages) * 8) / 1024 AS DataSpaceMB
FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON t.object_id = i.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.object_id
    AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
WHERE t.name NOT LIKE 'dt%'
    AND i.object_id > 255
    AND i.index_id <= 1
GROUP BY t.name
    ,i.object_id
    ,i.index_id
    ,i.name
ORDER BY object_name(i.object_id)
```

However, the following code fails to execute due to permissions, I cannot change the permissions nor grant any permisions to the user connecting from the application. I'd like to understand which join/table is failing to query so that I can remove the column or join from the syntax, or is there an alternative way to write the query to get around the error.

```
    SELECT TOP 10
  tables.name AS table_name,
  CAST(ROUND(((SUM(allocation_units.total_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS numeric(36, 2)) AS total_space_mb,
  CAST(ROUND(((SUM(allocation_units.used_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS numeric(36, 2)) AS used_space_mb,
  CAST(ROUND(((SUM(allocation_units.total_pages) - SUM(allocation_units.used_pages)) * 8) / 1024.00, 2) AS numeric(36, 2)) AS unused_space_mb,
  COUNT(DISTINCT indexes.index_id) AS indexes_count,
  MAX(dm_db_partition_stats.row_count) AS row_count,
  iif(MAX(ISNULL(user_seeks, 0)) = 0 AND MAX(ISNULL(user_scans, 0)) = 0 AND MAX(ISNULL(user_lookups, 0)) = 0, 1, 0) AS no_reads,
  iif(MAX(ISNULL(user_updates, 0)) = 0, 1, 0) AS no_writes,
  MAX(ISNULL(user_seeks, 0)) AS user_seeks,
  MAX(ISNULL(user_scans, 0)) AS user_scans,
  MAX(ISNULL(user_lookups, 0)) AS user_lookups,
  MAX(ISNULL(user_updates, 0)) AS user_updates,
  MAX(last_user_seek) AS last_user_seek,
  MAX(last_user_scan) AS last_user_scan,
  MAX(last_user_lookup) AS last_user_lookup,
  MAX(last_user_update) AS last_user_update,
  MAX(tables.create_date) AS create_date,
  MAX(tables.modify_date) AS modify_date
FROM sys.tables
LEFT JOIN sys.indexes
  ON tables.object_id = indexes.object_id
LEFT JOIN sys.partitions
  ON indexes.object_id = partitions.object_id
  AND indexes.index_id = partitions.index_id
LEFT JOIN sys.allocation_units
  ON partitions.partition_id = allocation_units.container_id
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
  ON tables.object_id = dm_db_index_usage_stats.object_id
  AND indexes.index_id = dm_db_index_usage_stats.index_id
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_db_partition_stats
  ON tables.object_id = dm_db_partition_stats.object_id
  AND indexes.index_id = dm_db_partition_stats.index_id
GROUP BY tables.name
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

[image]

```
26/08/2022 00:00:05 js  SCR-160012 JavaScript: error while evaluating script 'adbDatabaseAnalysis/js'.
26/08/2022 00:00:05 js  r_seek,    max(last_user_scan) as last_user_scan,    max(last_user_lookup) as last_user_lookup,    max(last_user_update) as last_user_update,    max(tables.create_date) as create_date,    max(tables.modify_date) as modify_date  from    sys.tables   left 
26/08/2022 00:00:05 js  join sys.indexes on tables.object_id = indexes.object_id    left join sys.partitions on indexes.object_id = partitions.object_id    and indexes.index_id = partitions.index_id    left join sys.allocation_units on partitions.partition_id = allocation_units
26/08/2022 00:00:05 js  .container_id    left join sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats on tables.object_id = dm_db_index_usage_stats.object_id    and indexes.index_id = dm_db_index_usage_stats.index_id    left join sys.dm_db_partition_stats on tables.object_id = dm_db_partition_stats.o
26/08/2022 00:00:05 js  bject_id    and indexes.index_id = dm_db_partition_stats.index_id  group by    tables.name  order by    2 DESC' could not be executed.
26/08/2022 00:00:05 js  und(       (         (           sum(allocation_units.used_pages) * 8         ) / 1024.00       ),        2     ) as numeric(36, 2)   ) as used_space_mb,    cast(     round(       (         (           sum(allocation_units.total_pages) - sum(allocation_u
26/08/2022 00:00:05 js  nits.used_pages)         ) * 8       ) / 1024.00,        2     ) as numeric(36, 2)   ) as unused_space_mb,    count(distinct indexes.index_id) as indexes_count,    max(     dm_db_partition_stats.row_count   ) as row_count,    iif(     max(       isnull(u
26/08/2022 00:00:05 js  ser_seeks, 0)     ) = 0      and max(       isnull(user_scans, 0)     ) = 0      and max(       isnull(user_lookups, 0)     ) = 0,      1,      0   ) as no_reads,    iif(     max(       isnull(user_updates, 0)     ) = 0,      1,      0   ) as no_writes, 
26/08/2022 00:00:05 js     max(     isnull(user_seeks, 0)   ) as user_seeks,    max(     isnull(user_scans, 0)   ) as user_scans,    max(     isnull(user_lookups, 0)   ) as user_lookups,    max(     isnull(user_updates, 0)   ) as user_updates,    max(last_user_seek) as last_use
26/08/2022 00:00:05 js  ODB-240000 ODBC error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The user does not have permission to perform this action. SQLState: 37000
26/08/2022 00:00:05 js  WDB-200001 SQL statement 'select top 10  tables.name as table_name,    cast(     round(       (         (           sum(allocation_units.total_pages) * 8         ) / 1024.00       ),        2     ) as numeric(36, 2)   ) as total_space_mb,    cast(     ro
26/08/2022 00:00:05 js  ODB-240000 ODBC error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]VIEW SERVER STATE permission was denied on object 'server', database 'master'. SQLState: 37000
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: but the first query works on sys.tables sys.indexes sys.partitions sys.allocation_units it doesnt return error.

Comment: Interesting, it has access to `sys.dm_db_partition_stats` but not `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`

Comment: @DaleK That is a complete fallacy: many `sys` tables/views actually live on the current database. *Certain* ones live in `master`, and not all of them need `VIEW SERVER STATE`, for example `sys.databases`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Documentation for `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-usage-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#permissions) says:

> **Permissions**
>
> On SQL Server and SQL Managed Instance, requires `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission.
>
> On SQL Database Basic, S0, and S1 service objectives, and for databases in elastic pools, the server admin account, the Azure Active Directory admin account, or membership in the `##MS_ServerStateReader##` server role is required. On all other SQL Database service objectives, either the `VIEW DATABASE STATE` permission on the database, or membership in the `##MS_ServerStateReader##` server role is required.

Meanwhile, `sys.dm_db_partition_stats` [can also be problematic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-partition-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#permissions), although it doesn't require server level permissions

> **Permissions**
>
> Requires `VIEW DATABASE STATE` and `VIEW DEFINITION` permissions to query the `sys.dm_db_partition_stats` dynamic management view. For more information about permissions on dynamic management views, see Dynamic Management Views and Functions (Transact-SQL).

The other views should be OK, but they will only show objects that the user has permissions on.